# Linking issue on Debian8

Tags: c, linux, linker, debian

I'm trying to recompile my software for debian 8, but i have run into this strange issue of libgssappi refusing to link with anything.

```
>~/torque_github$ gcc test.c -lgssapi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The library is present in the system, as seen here:

```
>~/torque_github$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gssapi
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
        libgssapi.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3
```

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig -a` as root?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `/sbin/ldconfig.real: invalid option -- 'a'`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch And I didn't completely change my question, as you can see in the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Debian/Jessie/x86-64 system, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so` is provided (according to `dpkg -S`) by the `libkrb5-dev` package and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3` is provided by `libgssapi3-heimdal` package (and I don't have any `libgssapi*dev` package).

You probably should install both of them (with `sudo aptitude install libkrb5-dev libgssapi3-heimdal` command), and use `pkg-config` with `krb5-gssapi`  to get compilation and linking flags.

```
gcc -Wall -g $(pkg-config --cflags krb5-gssapi) \
   test.c \
   $(pkg-config --libs krb5-gssapi) \
   -o myprog
```

<sup>(you could have to change your `test.c` source code if some API has changed; perhaps you'll need to `#include <krb5/krb5.h>`)</sup>

You might even use `gcc -v`  instead of `gcc` above.

Remember that order of arguments to `gcc` matters a big lot. Your initial question had a different order (and that is enough to make `gcc` fail)!

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. But just to make sure I have tested the order you suggested with the same result and modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I rewrote my answer entirely. I hope it is relevant now.

Comment: The `pkg-config` seems to be solution.